# XNA changing blendstate from alpha to Additive

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

Here's my problem
I am using a depth control but now i have different sprites that need different blendstates
how can i change this if I already started the spritebatch.begin(...)

I was trying to change spritebatch.graphicsDevice.blendstate but it doesn't seems to be working

I cannot turn a black area into transparency

Thank you

Still seems it cannot save the layer order between them by using that code... 
I guess the problem might be in using object.draw(spritebatch) and then draw inside the method.
I think theres a problem because i have 2 classes each one with a draw method with input spritebatch
this is what im doing

spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack, BlendState.Additive);
d.drawAttack(gameTime, spriteBatch);
spriteBatch.End();

spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
drawObjects(gameTime, spriteBatch);
charactersDraw(gameTime, spriteBatch); // same class as the d.drawAttack
spriteBatch.End();

they both draw but the layer !BETWEEN both spritebatche! doesn't seems to make any difference

 
the layerdepth works fine with characters and draw objects... only doesn't work with drawAttack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do multiple SpriteBatch.Begin() .. End() calls, [each with a different BlendState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433698.aspx). You can still preserve your layerDepth among them.

For example:

```
batch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack, BlendState.Additive);
batch.Draw(tex1, sprite1, null, Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero, 1.0f,
SpriteEffects.None, layer1);
batch.Draw(tex2, sprite2, null, Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero, 1.0f,
SpriteEffects.None, layer2);
batch.End();

//new blend state, new begin...end
batch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
batch.Draw(tex3, sprite3, null, Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero, 1.0f,
SpriteEffects.None, layer3);
batch.Draw(tex4, sprite4, null, Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero, 1.0f,
SpriteEffects.None, layer4);
batch.End();
```

Comment: Are you using the layerDepth parameter as in my example? With FrontToBack the lower layer values (like 0.3f) will show in front of the higher ones (like 0.9f).

Comment: after some threads and forums I think I might have to pre-calculate the depth for each object and then draw all of them (like a list)????? my layerDepth is calculated with a function when the object is drawn. The layer depth is working fine with objects and characters... the only problem is between spriteBatchs (with d.drawAttack), maybe theres a way to replace the black background of the image and draw it with alphablend?

Comment: Well, the <black background = alpha> is a separate issue. You can do that by selecting your texture image in the Content project, expand "Content Processor", then expand "Color Key Color". The default is a pinkish color. Make this black (0 R, 0 G, 0 B). Make sure "Color Key Enabled" is true also. Rebuild your project and your black should turn into alpha.

Comment: I'm using this free sprite <br/> http://www.ironstarmedia.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/particle-sheet-01.png <br/> and i already tried that method, somehow it keeps the black arround it. I though maybe was another kind of black but thats not the case. <br/> I read some stuff about premultiplied alpha and tried to change the parameters. <br/> I also found some other sprites I can use instead but that doesn't solve my problem... only avoid it :)

Comment: It's possible that black is not pure black (0, 0, 0). Look at it in an image editor and find out what color that background is. Use that as the Color Key.